# Срабатывает OnDateChangeListener

Tags: java, android

На версии андроида 4.1.1 автоматически срабатывает слушатель как только создаётся фрагмент, хотя пользователь ничего не нажимает. Как можно исправить этот баг?

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener {

public static final String TAG = "CalendarFragment";

public interface OnDateSelectListener {
    void onDateSelect(Date date);
}

private OnDateSelectListener listener;

public static CalendarFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    CalendarFragment fragment = new CalendarFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_pane_today).setOnClickListener(this);
    view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_pane_tomorrow).setOnClickListener(this);

    final TextView todayDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.today_date);
    todayDate.setText(DateUtils.getTodayDate().toAdvString(Constants.DATE_CALENDAR_FORM));

    final TextView tomorrowDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tomorrow_date);
    tomorrowDate.setText(DateUtils.getTomorrowDate().toAdvString(Constants.DATE_CALENDAR_FORM));

    final RangeCalendarView calendarView = (RangeCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    if (null != calendarView) {
        calendarView.setRange(59);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        listener = (OnDateSelectListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnDateSelectListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Date date = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.calendar_pane_today:
            date = DateUtils.getTodayDate();
            break;
        case R.id.calendar_pane_tomorrow:
            date = DateUtils.getTomorrowDate();
            break;
    }
    listener.onDateSelect(date);
}

@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    Date date = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth) : new Date(view.getDate());
    listener.onDateSelect(date);
}

}
```

И сам RangeCalendarView

```
public class RangeCalendarView extends CalendarView {

private static final int MIN_RANGE = 1000;

public RangeCalendarView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RangeCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RangeCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public RangeCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public void setRange(int days) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis() - MIN_RANGE);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
    setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}

}
```